# Firebase Messaging Upstream for Android is not firing

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a project with multiple `flavours` and multiple `buildType`.

I'll illustrate my project structure first before continuing:

```
app
   - src
       - main
       - flavour1
       - flavour2
```

Above is my current project structure. I'll now paste below my `build.gradle`

```
productFlavors {
    flavour1 {
        applicationId "com.myproject.flavour1"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

    }
    flavour2 {
        applicationId "com.myproject.flavour2"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        debuggable true
    }
    qa {
        applicationIdSuffix '.qa'
        debuggable true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
}   

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now what I want to accomplish is to have a specific `google-services.json` for each build variant so that I can use different Firebase Cloud Messaging projects per build variant.

Something like this:

```
 app
    - src
       - main
       - flavour1
          - debug
             - google-services.json <-- connected to Debug FCM Project
          - qa 
             - google-services.json <-- connected to QA FCM Project
       - flavour2
          - debug
             - google-services.json <-- connected to Debug FCM Project
          - qa 
             - google-services.json <-- connected to QA FCM Project
```

I tried this method, and it's not working at all. None of the upstream messages are being sent to the server. I tried moving the `google-services.json` to the root and deleted all the other `json` files and then I found that messages were now being sent. I thought this was supported with `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`, which was something I included in my `build.gradle` file.

If I'm missing a step or if I'm doing something incorrectly, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 72 hours of recreating multiple projects to mimic my file structure, I was able to narrow it down to this problem and I hope this may be of use to someone who experiences this:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(this));
```

I was placing the above line of code into my `Application` class because my project was always requiring me to do so. Most of the sample apps didn't require me to have to manually intialize `FirebaseApp` since it's supposed to be done automatically but for some weird reason, my project always required me to do this.

After doing some digging, I noticed a `Log` in my console stating:

`D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.`

This was my 'AHA!' moment. Then after a little bit more digging, I found that the problem was chillin`like a villain` inside my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I had the following tag:

```
<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    tools:node="replace"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_my_app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> ...
```

If you notice, I have a tag `tools:node="replace"`. Turns out that with this line, it will NOT intialize my `FirebaseApp`. Using this actually replaces the declaration of lower priority.

I ended up replacing this line and voila! `FirebaseApp` was linking successfully and upstream messages began to work!

I also didn't create a `google-services.json` file for each flavour build type. I instead created a folder for each `buildType` and stored my `google-services.json` in there.

Looks like this:

```
app
- src
   - debug
      - google-services.json <-- connected to Debug FCM Project
   - qa
      - google-services.json <-- connected to QA FCM Project
   - release
      - google-services.json <-- connected to Release FCM Project
   - flavour1
   - flavour2
```

Each of the `google-services.json` configuration files within each `buildType` package has all the `productFlavours` inside so whenever I run a specific build variant, it loads up the proper configuration file.